# If i Use third party libraries for AES encryption does App Store accepts my app?

Tags: encryption, ios11, xcode9

From my iOS app i want to send encrypted(AES) username and password to the http server.

For this i found RNCryptor like third party API's. If i use this library in my app, does app store accepts my app. Also i want to know is there any apple related standard swift library for AES encryption?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The App store does not in general terms reject app for using encryption such as AES. It doesn't matter that you use 3rd party frameworks such `RNCryptor`, `CryptoSwift` or write your own implementation.

It is your responsibility to comply with Export Compliance (no matter if your app should be distributed only outside of U.S.). For this you will need to either provide correct value for `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` key (Boolean value) in your target properties of your app or set it every time you submit new build to iTunesConnect. As these requirements do change I suggest you read up on this topic e.g. at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH33-SW6.

And as far as I am aware, Apple does not provide "Crypto" frameworks for Swift, only the "Common Crypto API." Samples can be found at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CryptoCompatibility/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thank u @Peter for your valuable suggestion. My main ambiguity is, if i use third party library to do this in my app, what are the important steps should i take before submitting to the app store.

Comment: I've updated the answer to be explicit about use of 3rd party frameworks. There are no special steps when using them. The important part is the legal part about compliance with export laws. I cannot advise on specifics there. If you require help in this regards I suggest you consult a lawyer familiar with these topics.